# How get a object from NSSet by name

Tags: ios, objective-c, getter, nsset

I have simple core data model. I have student, who has parents - NSSet. When I have this code:

```
if(!student.parents.count == 0){
    Parent *mother = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Parent" inManagedObjectContext:cdh.context];
    [student addParentsObject:mother];
}
```

How can I get later the object "mother" from the NSSet (studen.parents)? Thank you.

How can I edit the object mother? For example mother has attribute name (mother.name). How can I edit the attribute the simplest? I think by student, not only the object mother. For example I know, that I want to edit mother from student, who has ID "XXX". How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (if it is a problem) is that you have done nothing to indicate that a particular parent *is* the "mother". There is no "object `mother`" in the set of parents. The word "mother" is *not* a "name" in any meaningful sense whatever.

When you added the parent in the code above, you used a *variable* named "mother", but that is just a temporary reference; it does not designate anything about the object to which this variable points, the object that is now added as a Parent (and the variable vanishes in a puff of smoke two lines later in any case). It would not make the slightest difference if the variable name had been `scrumdiddlyumptious`:

```
Parent * scrumdiddlyumptious = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Parent" inManagedObjectContext:cdh.context];
[student addParentsObject: scrumdiddlyumptious];
```

The effect would be *exactly* the same as in your code.

Ultimately, this is an issue with your model. Your model is faulty in relation to your future desires. If knowing that a particular parent is a "mother" is important to you, it is up to *you* to have an *attribute in the Parent entity* which you can set to indicate that. Now you can fetch based on that attribute.

Comment: Thanks, if I understand your answer the solution is: add a attribute for example "type" and then decode what type of parent it is. For example if(parent.type == "mother") than I have a object mother. Ok it's seems like a possible option. Thank you.

Comment: @user3365839 It all depends on how fine-grained you want to be. You need to plan ahead. "type" as a string is a bit dangerous because what if you mistype the string "mother" as "mither"? If you believe that a parent either is or is not a mother, then it would be better for this to be a boolean. If you also believe that a parent either is a "mother" or a "father" and there are no other possibilities, then that boolean is all you need, since true would be mean a "mother" and false would mean a "father", provided you remembered to deal with this every time you make a Parent.